# when defer func is executed at ginkgo

Tags: go, kubernetes, ginkgo

I'm rewriting unit test of our k8s controller with ginkgo.

As previous TDD, for each test, we will have something like.

```golang
    // Create the Channel  object and expect the Reconcile
    g.Expect(c.Create(context.TODO(), myObj)).NotTo(gomega.HaveOccurred())
    defer c.Delete(context.TODO(),myObj)
```

What we want is, create an object for a test and delete it from the underline cluster after this test.

Now, on `ginkgo`, we are running tests within `spec` of containers. To me the `container` is the origin process, if that's the case does it mean the `defer` defined within the `It` spec will execute before exiting `container` instead of exiting the `It` spec.

For example,

```golang
var _ = Describe("my desr", func(){
   It("a", func(){
     fmt.Println(100)
     defer func(){fmt.Println("a", 100)}()
   })

   It("b", func(){
     fmt.Println(200)
     defer func(){fmt.Println("b", 200)}()
  })
})
```

Would the result be:

**a**

```
100
a100
200
b200
```

Or

**b**

```
100
200
b200
a100
```

In my case, I definitely what the first behavior. Or I'm in the wrong direction in terms of getting the `defer` behavior? I mean, should I look into the `BeforeEach` and `AfterEach` approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you plan to run tests in parallel? If so, then results will be unpredictable. In that case it's recommended to have a separate instance of external resources for each process.

I would recommend to look at how [controller tests are implemented in controller-runtime](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/blob/df180accb901c816ced95a7b1a6eaf2c801f3560/pkg/controller/controller_integration_test.go). I believe, they create new Control Plane with [envtest](https://godoc.org/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/envtest) each time [`BeforeSuit` function](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/controller-runtime/blob/master/pkg/controller/controller_suite_test.go#L59) is called. And as [ginkgo docs](https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/#global-setup-and-teardown-beforesuite-and-aftersuite) states:

> when running in parallel, each parallel process will run BeforeSuite and AfterSuite functions

Comment: thanks for the heads-up, I'm looking into the envtest.

Answer (score 4):

You would see the first behavior, because the enclosing scope of the `defer`s is the same anonymous function as the previous `Println`. `defer`red functions get called when exiting the scope.

Answer (score 2):

"Origin process" has nothing to do with it. [Defer statements run when the surrounding function returns](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Defer_statements). In your case, the surrounding function is your anonymous `func()` passed to (and called by) `It`.